# MSI SQL Query for column header called "Table" not working

Tags: sql, powershell, windows-installer

I'm using Powershell to query the _Validation table from an MSI Code as follows...

```
$Script:WindowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$Script:MSIDatabase = 
$WindowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", 
"InvokeMethod", $null, $WindowsInstaller, @($MSIPath, 0))  
$Query = "SELECT Table, Column FROM _Validation"
$Script:View = $MSIDatabase.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView", 
"InvokeMethod", $null, $MSIDatabase, ($Query))
$Script:View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, 
$null)
$Record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $null, 
$View, $null)
    $ValidationTable =@()
    While($Record -ne $null){


    $Col1 =  $Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", "GetProperty", 
$null, $Record, 1)
    $Col2 =  $Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", "GetProperty", 
$null, $Record, 2)
    $ValidationTable += New-Object PsObject -Property @{Table = $Col1; 
Column = $Col2}
    $Record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $null, 
$View, $null)



    }

    }
```

Now everything is working except for when I use "Table" in the query. From research I understand it may be an escape word in SQL so I've tried wrapping it in ` I've tired [  I've tried _Validation.Table and nothing works. 
As I'm not good with SQL can anyone give me a hand? 
Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy badger... the issue wasn't with the query it was with the fact i wrapped the query in double quotes not single quotes...

```
$Query = 'SELECT `Table`, Column FROM _Validation'
```

Works great.